# SplashScreen crashes when device screen is turned off

Tags: android

Dears I'm trying to make splash screen as fragment showing imageView the start another fragment after 5 sec

here is the activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Fragment fragment = null;
// Splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragment = new SplashFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        /*
         * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
         * want to show case your app logo / company
         */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                fragment = new LoginFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);


    }

} }
```

`SplashFragment` should be start first on  many activity created

then `LoginFragment` should be started after 5 seconds

Comment: this is the exception message   
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at fragmentTransaction.commit(); inside run()

Comment: can u change your manifest ?

Comment: change my manifest to what ?

Comment: You can not perform transaction in Activity's Pause state .

Comment: @ADM so what should i do  ?

Comment: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/   have a look on this link, your way for splash is weird

Comment: Your answer is in above link . Cause you are performing delayed task so you need to check for Activity's state first .